# Focused row not working - Gridview

Tags: vb.net, gridview, devexpress

I am using Dev Express to develop a form in which i have a GridControl with a View inside a View.

It looks like this: [image]

I am then trying to use the event ValidatingEditor to validate the user input.
I tried to do that by doing:

```
 Private Sub grvObsAM_Artigos_ValidatingEditor(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.BaseContainerValidateEditorEventArgs) Handles grvObsAM_Artigos.ValidatingEditor


    Dim row As Integer = Me.grvObsAM_Artigos.FocusedRowHandle
```

This, however always returns me something like -99999.. 
I poked around and tried this other solution using the sender from the event:

```
 Private Sub grvObsAM_Artigos_ValidatingEditor(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.BaseContainerValidateEditorEventArgs) Handles grvObsAM_Artigos.ValidatingEditor

    Dim grv As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView = CType(sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView)
    Dim row As Integer = grv.FocusedRowHandle
```

And using this second solution i managed to get the focused row handle. Even though this worked this time (because the event was triggered by the view itself and i had access to the sender) this doesn't solve my problem as there are other events where the sender is not the view and the problem persists.
Usign Me.grvObsAM_Artigos."insert anything here" doesn't seem to work properly.

Does anyone have any idea on why this is happening? Am i missing something?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is actually that you have several of the grvObsAM_Artigos gridviews.  One for each row that has the details.  So you need to use the view above ti to access the proper one.  Using:

```
Dim grv as XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView = grvObsAM.GetDetailView(RowHandle, 0)
```

That should give you the right instance of the gridView you want.  Everytime a master row is expanded and collapsed, the child is created and destroyed respectively.

This should give you a bit more background.

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_GetDetailViewtopic

Comment: Yep, that makes perfect sense. I'm a bit ashamed of not thinking that myself actually :P However, i didn't quite understand your line of code on how i'm supposed to get the view that i'm working on.

Comment: That line of code is using the a row in the master view, to find the proper detailGridview for that row masterRow.  So for example, lets say you wanted to access the detailView for the currently focused MasterView Row.  MasterGridView.GetVisibleDetailView(MasterGridView.GetFocusedRowHandle,0)  If there is a specific example you have in mind to try to access the detailGrid for Let me know, I can try to give you that specific example.

Comment: Each Master View row contains it's own child view.  In order took up the an item in the child view you need to first find the master row that was selected.  That's what the line of code does.  It uses the selected row handle of the Master row to select the correct master row, then pulls out the detail view from it.